# ArcGIS Pro attribute table question

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table

I'm in the middle of the transition from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro. I have many records that I need to review. In ArcMap, I pan to the record (ctrl + N), use the down arrow key to go to the next record. In ArcGIS Pro, I pan to the record but when I use the arrow key it nudges the map. Does anyone know how to keep the attribute table active?

Answer (score 0):

The arrow key press will be handled by which ever view is active.  Click on the attribute table's title (tab) to make it active, then press the down arrow if you want to go to the next record down.

Comment: My question was if there was a way to keep the attribute table active. After panning the record, the active view becomes the map. I would like to keep the attribute table active to avoid clicking and having to take my hands off the keyboard altogether.

Comment: You may need to explain further (or perhaps your ArcGIS Pro behaves differently to mine).  When I pan the table it remains the active view.

Comment: Interesting, I'm wondering if it's a version issue. In a different forum, somebody mentioned the behavior you experience but after a version update now experiences what I do.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then.  You should probably report it to ESRI as a support issue.